# ¿Como pasar token con angular 5 y httpclient?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4

Necesito pasar el *token* que me viene de la base de datos para que *laravel* me deje entrar al contenido. Aquí dejo mi código

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {SessionStorageService} from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

public sesion = false;

user: any = <any>{};



constructor(public _http:HttpClient, 
public _local:SessionStorageService,
public _rutas:Router
) { 

}

 login(a:NgForm){



 const url = 'http://localhost/api/public/login';

this._http.post(url,{
'username':this.user.username,
'password':this.user.password

}).subscribe(data => {

        this.user = data;
        this.sesion = true;
    this._local.store('user',data);
    this._rutas.navigate(['main']);

  console.log('ha ido bien');
  console.log(data);

  }, error => {

 console.log('error');
this.sesion = false;
 });

 }
```

Esta función me devuelve el usuario con los datos que le paso del html

[image: como recogeria el token en la misma funcion y se lo enviaria como cabezera a laravel??]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor solución es implementar [Interceptores Http](https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors) y agregar automáticamente las cabeceras necesarias en este caso agregar el Token a la cabecera.

Te dejo un ejemplo de una implementación que tengo:

token.interceptor.ts

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthSessionService } from './auth-session.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authSession: AuthSessionService,
        private auth: AuthService
    ) {}


    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authRequest = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `JWT ${this.authSession.token}`)});
        return next.handle(authRequest).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // do stuff with response if you want
            }
        }, (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
                    this.auth.logout();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

en el modulo

```
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AuthSessionService } from './auth/auth-session.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './auth/token.interceptor';



@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: TokenInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        AuthSessionService,
        AuthService,
        AuthGuard
    ]
})
export class ServiciosModule { }
```

Comment: me pierdo si pudieras adaptar mi codigo a eso te lo agradeceria mucho ya he hecho la importacion en el modulo pero en la clase no tengo idea

Comment: Es que poco mas lo tenes que copiar y pegar, solo tenes que poner donde obtienes el token, registrarlo como Interceptor al servicio en tu app.module o donde lo utilices (se llama token.interceptor.ts el archivo) y automaticamente cuando uses `HttpClient` el token estara incluido, solo deje los elementos de authenticacíon que uso 2 servicios uno para loguearse y otro para mantener los datos del login que seria el token. Sino revisa el enlace del articulo donde esta explicado